# an inequality for non-negative scalars

Tags: inequality

Let $1< p < \infty$ for non-negative scalars $x$, $y$ we have $(x+y)^p \geq x^p + y^p$

Is there a similar inequality for $ p \leq 1 $

Answer (score 4):

Well, then from Power Means Inequality you have:
$$\frac{x+y}2 \geqslant \sqrt[p]{\frac{x^p+y^p}2} \iff (x+y)^p \geqslant \frac1{2^{1-p}}(x^p+y^p)$$

Answer (score 0):

Does this inequation $\sqrt{1+2} \ge \sqrt{1}+\sqrt{2}$ hold?

Comment: I think for $ p\leq 1$ we have $(x+y)^p \leq x^p +y^p$